# Angularjs .factory method return

Tags: angularjs, methods, return, factory

I have been able to get this .factory to work by adding a "return" in front of both the Restangular.all statement and the response. My question is why is it needed there? Why can't I just return the response?

```
app.controller('MainController', ['GetIndexesFromES', '$scope', function(GetIndexesFromES, $scope) {
        $scope.indices = GetIndexesFromES.getUniqueIndexIDs();
        console.log($scope.indices);
}]);

app.factory('GetIndexesFromES', ['Restangular', function GetIndexesFromES (Restangular) {
    var GetIndexesFromES = {};
    GetIndexesFromES.getUniqueIndexIDs = function(){
        return Restangular.all('_stats/index,store').getList().then(function(response) {
            return response
        });
    }
    return GetIndexesFromES;
}]);
```

The main reason why I'm asking this question is that I want to modify the data (within the .factory) before sending it back to the controller/$scope.

Thank you,
Gregg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully look at your code for `getUniqueIndexIDs` you will realize there is a callback.

The second return is not a return from `getUniqueIndexIDs` but from your `then`'s callback function.

Essentially your `getUniqueIndexIDs` returns a promise created by `then`. This promise is resolved by the return value `then` callback function which in your case is `return response`.

What you are essentially doing is promise chaining.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay. I had changed my code to this: ` getIndexesFromES.getUniqueIndexIDs = function(){
  var localResponse = [];
      Restangular.all('_stats/index,store').getList().then(function(response) {
             angular.copy(listOfUniqueIndices(response), localResponse);
        });
        return localResponse;
    }`

In regards to your response it took me a while to understand all of what you were saying. The following link and sections helped:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
section: The Promise API
section: Chaining promises

Thank you for your response/help.

Comment: Yes i realize that, need a better way to explain it.